# Parsing array in library constructor - Pointer problem (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, arduino

I am trying to develop an Arduino library that consists out of two classes. I want 'WayPointStack' to store an array of 'WPCommand', but I can't get it to work.

It is obviously a pointer problem, but I don't know how to solve it. There are four errors left in my code:

```
WayPointStack.cpp:23:7: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'WPCommand*' to 'WPCommand [0]'
_wp = new WPCommand[arrSize]; //Fixed

WayPointStack.cpp:44:34: error: could not convert '(operator new(16u), (((WPCommand*)<anonymous>)->WPCommand::WPCommand(4, 10000), ((WPCommand*)<anonymous>)))' from 'WPCommand*' to 'WPCommand'
return new WPCommand(_END, 10000);

WayPointStack.cpp:59:15: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'WPCommand' and 'WPCommand*')
_wp[pointer] = new WPCommand(target, time); # Fixed

WPCommand.h:10:7: note: candidate: WPCommand& WPCommand::operator=(const WPCommand&)
class WPCommand # Does not appear anymore, fixed
```

WPCommand.h

```
#ifndef WPCommand_h
#define WPCommand_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class WPCommand
{
  public:
    WPCommand(int target, int time );
    WPCommand();
    int GetTarget();
    int GetTime();
    int LEFT;
    int RIGHT;
    int FORWARD;
    int BACKWARD;
    int STOP;
    int END;
  private:
    int _target;
    int _time;
};
#endif
```

WayPointStack.h

```
#ifndef WayPointStack_h
#define WayPointStack_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "WPCommand.h"

class WayPointStack
{
  public:
    WayPointStack();
    WayPointStack(WPCommand wp[], int length);
    WPCommand GetNextWP();
    WPCommand GetWP(int i);
    void AddWP(int target, int time);
    int SetWPPointer(int i);
    int GetWPPointer();
    int GetLength();
  private:
    WPCommand _wp[];
    int pointer;
    int _length;
};

#endif
```

WayPointStack.cpp (partly)

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "WayPointStack.h"
#include "WPCommand.h"
#define _BACKWARD 0
#define _FORWARD 1
#define _STOP 2
#define _LEFT 3
#define _RIGHT 4
#define _END 4
#define arrSize 100

WayPointStack::WayPointStack()
{
  _wp = new WPCommand[arrSize];
  _length = 0;
  pointer = 0;
}

WayPointStack::WayPointStack(WPCommand wp[], int length)
{
    _wp = new WPCommand[arrSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        _wp[i] = wp[i];
    }
    _length = length;
    pointer = 0;
}

WPCommand WayPointStack::GetNextWP()
{
    if (pointer < _length){
        pointer++;
        return _wp[pointer-1];
    }
    return new WPCommand(_END, 10000);
}
```

I tried to more or less randomly reference and derefence _wp and wp[] but it did not work.

**Edit:**
Changing

```
WPCommand _wp[];
```

to

```
WPCommand *_wp;
```

successfully fixed the first error. Doing the same to

```
WayPointStack(WPCommand *wp, int length);
```

Edit:

```
_wp[pointer] = WPCommand(target, time);
```

instead of

```
_wp[pointer] = new WPCommand(target, time);
```

successfully fixed error number 3.

Edit:

```
return WPCommand(_END, 10000);
```

fixed error number 2.

Problem solved.

Comment: `WPCommand _wp[];` is not a valid definition. You need to make it a pointer: `WPCommand *_wp;`

Comment: Does your code compile when you declare a zero sized array `WPCommand _wp[];` in your class `WayPointStack`?

Comment: Thank you. I got rid of the first error. But declaring a zero sized array had no effect at all. I updated the question

Comment: Are you sure that you do not want to make your life simple by using a container class like `std::vector`? (Likewise, those `#define _BACKWARD 0` look like you want to use an `enum` instead.)

Comment: Second error might be fixed by using braces, `return (new WPCommand(_END, 10000));`. Kind of strange to return something that does have nothing to do with the object, though.

Comment: In the third error, you get the element of an array, which is of non-pointer type, and you assign a pointer to it. As the error does not happen in the code you posted, no idea what you try there, but should be clear why this can't work.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem (error 2). The whole system is about letting a small robot move long a path with given speed. (move forward for one second, then rotate left for 0.25 seconds..) If there are no commands left, send an 'end command'.Since the iterator function requires a WPCommand object, I just chose this way. And yes, you are correct. I should use an enum instead. It's on my list. =)

Comment: I got rid of the third error by referencing it. I think this should do the job. Thank you very much. But error number two is this there. The braces did not fix it.

Comment: @Kruspe you introduced new problems with your changes :-( ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378196/creating-a-second-instance-of-an-object-changes-whole-class-behavior-c )

Comment: Is that a bad thing? I thought it's a new question and so the right thing to do :/

Comment: Next time, please answer with an @user, if you don't, I don't get a notification that you answered to my comment (you get notifications about my comments because it's your question). Now, I took another look at error two: your function is of non-pointer return type, yet you try to return a pointer. Again: your function has the signature `WPCommand WayPointStack::GetNextWP()`, not `WPCommand* WayPointStack::GetNextWP()`. Either change the signature or return a non-pointer (`return WPCommand(_END, 10000);`, without the `new`)